# how to check for duplicate entries in database?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I need to apply a check so that a user cannot register using an email id which already exists in the database.

Comment: It's not clear: are you interfacing to mysql in Java?

Comment: Just select that email in database and see if its in. You might wanna tell what database your using and so on.

Comment: yes i am using my sql database.
and i have set emailid fied as primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this DAO method :

```
public boolean isDuplicateEntry(String email) {
        Session session = getSession();
        try {
            User user = (User) session.get(User.class, email);
            session.close();

            return (null != user);

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error("get failed", e);
            session.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend putting session.close() in a finally block. Not that its a huge deal but this is a classic example where you would want to use a finally block in my opinion.

Comment: @tkeE2036 you are right, @bhavna raghuvanshi you should put it somewhere where your DAO classes are

Answer (score 10):

Put a constraint on the email column, or select before insert.

Comment: +1 - *"or select before insert"* ... in the same transaction!

Comment: +1 - Enforce data constraints at the database level whenever possible (or practical).

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed basically two ways to achieve this:

1. Test if record exists before inserting, inside the same transaction. The `ResultSet#next()` of the `SELECT` should return `false`. Then do `INSERT`.
2. Just do `INSERT` anyway and determine if [`SQLException#getSQLState()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState%28%29) of any catched `SQLException` starts with `23` which is a constraint violation as per the [SQL specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). It can namely be caused by more factors than "just" a constraint violation. You should namely not handle every `SQLException` as a constraint violation.

   ```
   public static boolean isConstraintViolation(SQLException e) {
       return e.getSQLState().startsWith("23");
   }
   ```

I would opt for the first way as it is semantically more correct. It is in fact not an exceptional circumstance. You namely *know* that it is potentially going to happen. But it may potentially fail in heavy concurrent environment where transactions are *not* synchronized (either unawarely or to optimize performance). You may then want to determine the exception instead.

---

That said, you normally don't want to put a PK on an email field. They are namely subject to changes. Rather use a DB-managed autogenerated PK (MySQL: `BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`, Oracle/PostgreSQL: `SERIAL`, SQLServer: `IDENTITY`) and give the email field an `UNIQUE` key.

Comment: I would prefer the second to avoid two calls to the database. Agree with you about the email field. Not a good candidate for a primary key.

Comment: @HLGEM: A query on an indexed field is cheap. Creating an exception is expensive. I am not sure. Profile before microoptimizing or just don't microoptimize at all ;)

Comment: Exception should hit very rarely so it can be more expensive, one hit to the database vice two, happens with every insert. Ergo, it will in the long run be more expensive. But you are right when faced with multiple choices, it is a good idea to profile.

Answer (score 1):

Put a unique constraint on the relevant column in the database table. For example (MySQL):

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE (Email)
```

*edit* - If the e-mail field is already a primary key as you write in a comment above, then you don't need this, because primary keys are by definition unique. Then in Java you could catch the `SQLException` that you get if you'd insert a record with a primary key that already exists, or you can do a `SELECT ... WHERE Email=?` before you try the insert to see if there is already a record with that e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

You may:

- make the email field unique, try to insert and catch the exception

or

- make a select before each insert