# sun.misc.Unsafe.park triggered by JDBC calls

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

In our application we have seen threads spending a lot of time locked via a call to the `sun.misc.Unsafe.park` method. We have noticed that this pattern typically is triggered by JDBC calls to the database.

I do not know much about the `Unsafe.park` method. I am wondering whether this is normal behavior indicating that the thread is waiting for input from the DB, or if there is some synchronization issue with our application that we could improve.

Do you know which of the two it is? Alternatively, do you know ways in which we could investigate the matter further?

Comment: This indicates idle threads. Rather normal behaviour

Comment: but is it idle threads that are waiting for I/O, or idle threads that are stuck trying to synchronize with each other?

Comment: Check the stacktraces and you will know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sun.misc.Unsafe.park` is pretty much the same as thread.wait, but it uses architecture dependent code, due to the fact that `park` is native call, it can get the benefit in performance (it's a popular pattern in `java.util.concurrent`, e.g. you can see the usage of `park` in `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and `thread pooloing`). Obviously that you have a multithread environment and `db connections` use `thread pool` for own purposes. In the jdk `parking` brings significant optimization.

About your situation with JDBC, I would suggest a deadlock is going on in your case. All threads are waiting for some event. You can investigate a `deadlock`, I would like to advise you to read this articles:

> [jdbc-deadlock-avoidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300399/jdbc-deadlock-avoidance-question-basic)
>
> [jdbc and deadlocks manual](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3708511/Application-Handling-of-Database-Timeouts-and-Deadlocks.htm)

HTH

Comment: What is '`jdbs`'?

Comment: JDBC is an acronym, not a piece of Java code, and not in lowercase.

Comment: @rukavitsya Thanks for the answer, it is quite informative. One small remark, though. Are you suggesting that the deadlock is in the Java part, or is it a DB deadlock because of mishandling of transactions?

Comment: @ichfarbstift it's hard to say for sure, I suppose that `deadlock` is related to Java part.